# Need help figuring out how to solve a c++ code problem

Tags: c++, fstream

I am supposed to write a c++ program that reads a text.txt file named grades.txt, where the text file contains names and a grade next to it.
The program is supposed to read the text file and determine what student has the highest grade and display the name of that student. I also cannot use any existing function such as search, find, etc. and I cannot use any arrays or multidimensional data types.
I was able to figure out how to open the text file (and make sure it opened successfully) and I also know that I need a while loop maybe??
This is all I have right now. Any idea on how I can do this??

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int grade;
    string name;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("grades.txt");

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        while (fin >> grade && fin >> name)
        {
            if 
        }

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "failed to open file!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Example of data file.(the name with each grade is in a separate line in the file)

```
Velma 56
Linda 83
John 89
Isaac 75
Maggie 90
Seth 41 
June 96
Hunter 100
```

Comment: This sounds homework-y.

Comment: Please include a sample of the data file.  Paste as text.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample of the inner loop:

```
std::string student_name;
int grade;
//...
int highest_grade;
std::string student_highest_grade;
my_file >> highest_grade >> student_highest_grade;
while (my_file >> grade >> student_name)
{
    if (grade > highest_grade)
    {
        highest_grade = grade;
        student_highest_grade = student_name;
    }
}
```

You were proceeding nicely.  I filled in your `if` statement for you.